# How to change background color of datepicker in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I need to change the background white color of calendarDatePicker in android. I have tried so many links in SO. but nothing worked for me. So please share with me if you have any ideas. I know this is a duplicate question. but my requirement is completely different. that's why I post question here. need to change the light grey color to what color i want

**this is my calendar activity**

```
    public void calenderPicker() {
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    CalendarDatePickerDialog calendarDatePickerDialog = CalendarDatePickerDialog.newInstance(Personal.this, date.get(Calendar.YEAR), date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                               date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    calendarDatePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER);
    }
```

**this is my onDateset()**

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(CalendarDatePickerDialog calendarDatePickerDialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using a library to create this date time picker?

Comment: yes am using lib...but this is not a time picker..its just calendar date picker

Comment: @AnitaShalu change in the layout of the library

Comment: If you are using com.android.datetimepicker  you can change the colors in the layout of the libary

Comment: @Raghunandan i dont understand what r u trying to say

Comment: @cozeJ4 i have used  compile('com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.5.3') this lib in my gradle

Comment: @AnitaShalu check the resource files of the library used. modify it accordingly

Comment: @Raghunandan how can we change the resources of lib?? am using  compile('com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.5.3') this lib in my gradle. is it possible to change resources as you said?

Comment: @AnitaShalu gradle has nothing do with this. You can browse through the library resources files and modify it

Comment: @Raghunandan can you show me some links for my reference?

Comment: @AnitaShalu i have used this https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker which is similar to the image you posted. In the library under resources layout section there is date_picker_selected_date.xml. You can change the background there. I haven't used the same library you have used

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks buddy..let me check it out

Comment: Alternatively you can use this head over to  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/+/master   download the sources (tgz) import the it as a module library in your project and then customise  the dialogue to your liking in the xml files

Comment: You can change the background in date_picker_dialogue.xml of the library

Comment: @cozeJ4 thanks yaar...pls let me check it out

Comment: @Raghunandan hey man...below image in the link looks like mine. but they have changed the selected date color. is it possible to change background color?

Comment: @AnitaShalu yes it is possible and i have changed it myself read my previous comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User Raghunandhan pointed out exactly in comments where you have to change the background color exactly.

As he told you to look out this [github](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker) post.Moreover you can implement this in your project.

In `datetimepicker-library/res/layout/date_picker_selected_date.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/day_picker_selected_date_layout"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/date_picker_component_width"
    android:layout_height="0.0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:background="#C689F5"   //change the background color for your requirement
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

.........
.........
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]