# Android: change text color of DatePicker

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-styles, android-datepicker

I would like to change the color of the text/separators of my DatePicker ([Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlFAS.png) here in black to white).

PS: It's not a dialog.

```
<DatePicker
        style="@android:style/Widget.DatePicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: There's seems to be [some discussion of this already](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+change+color+of+datepicker&oq=android+change+color+of+datepicker&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i64j69i60.8326j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Al Lelopath Almost all of these topic talks about DatePickerDialog or non-spinner DatePicker.

Comment: @DazzTv see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096587/how-to-change-background-color-of-datepicker-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42367430/7012517